# boost version conflict between statically linked library and dynamically library?

Tags: c++, undefined, lookup, symbols

We use a commercial software (say A.exe), which uses DSOs as plugins that must define certain functions , and one of its plugins (say B.so) is statically linked against boost-1.43 . According to its docs, B.so doesn't need boost::filesystem library, so it doesn't link in libboost_filesystem.a .

Now I am developing a plugin ( say C.so ) which is dynamically linked against boost-1.42 ( Edit : I tried boost-1.43 the one same as A.exe's B.so plugin , it didn't work and gave me the same symbol lookup error .), and C.so uses boost filesystem, and ldd C.so shows that libboost_filesytem.so can be found. 
The problem is that when I run my plugin C.so through A.exe, it says "A.exe: symbol lookup error : B.so undefined symbol boost::filesystem::detail::status_api(...)" .

Then when I debug it by running nm on B.so ( the plugin comes with A.exe ) to look for symbols, I find that run " nm -D -C B.so | grep ' U ' | grep boost" in shell gives me " U boost::filesystem::detail::status_api ", which means that B.so has an undefined symbol entry.

I am so confused that :

1) Will this way of mixing boost versions work at all ?

2) If as docs of A.exe said some boost libs were statically linked ( apparently filesystem was not needed so not linked ), why am I getting undefined symbol entry when running "nm -D -C B.so" ( -D is for dynamic symbol, -C is for demangling names) , and especially for boost filesytem lib?

3) Why am I getting a "symbol lookup error" when I run my plugin C.so through A.exe ? Should my plugin C.so just look for the already linked boost filesystem lib provided by me ? while not the one that statically linked in B.so plugin ?

4) Will the main exe always look for the first registered symbol entry even using plugin system , while not the one linked for my plugin?

5) Is this because the version conflict between two plugins ?

Any docs on how symbols are imported when loading plugins ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "A plugin is a guest in the host process" - you need to accept that if you don't wish to be dependent on the libraries loaded by other components, you have to link statically.

Comment: Thank you @Ben for commenting on my question. Do you mean that if boost is linked in any plugin of host process , then in host process's any other plugins, boost has to be statically linked as well ? Otherwise the host process will use the boost from other plugin ?

Comment: I mean that all the dynamically loaded boosts must be compatible with each other, and specifically with the first one to load, which will probably be the host process. So you have to compile the plugin to whatever version of boost the host uses (or whichever plugin was first). You can avoid that by making your plugin statically linked - then you are not dependent on the host or the order the plugins load. (But then you can't share boost types with the host, if you do).

Comment: I don't think even statically linking multiple different versions of Boost is OK, because there may be global variables in play that differs between the versions.  I have encountered a problem with this sort of thing before...I think with Boost Tokenizer or something surprising like that.  Don't mix Boost versions, period.

Comment: Thanks @Ben : Do you mean that if the main exe use dlopen (with RTLD_GLOBAL flag) to load the first dso plugin that has boost statically linked in, then the main exe will use these globally visible boost symbols for later boost calls even from other plugins ? If so and I can use same boost version but if the first plugin doesn't statically link every boost lib because it doesn't need it, I will end up with some symbol lookup error because I need those libs not included in first plugin ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck : Thanks. I am getting same error even I use same boost version. Now the question is : for the B.so plugin, the developer says boost was statically linked in (without boost_filesystem.a because it wasn't used) , but I found an undefined symbol called boost::filesystem::detail::status_api when running command nm -D -C on this B.so plugin. It seems that this undefined symbol is blocking any other plugins from using boost::filesystem. Am I right on this ?

Comment: @Ben : Thanks. I am getting same error even I use same boost version. Now the question is : for the B.so plugin, the developer says boost was statically linked in (without boost_filesystem.a because it wasn't used) , but I found an undefined symbol called boost::filesystem::detail::status_api when running command nm -D -C on this B.so plugin. It seems that this undefined symbol is blocking any other plugins from using boost::filesystem. Am I right on this ?

Comment: I am afraid I have reached the end of my knowledge! It sounds like this is the issue but I cannot say for sure.